# Find the 5th element with a specified class in a list and add another class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I'd like to `addClass "green"` to the 5th `li.hr` in every `ul` containers in my site.

```
$("ul li.hr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).length = 5) {
    $(this).addClass("green");
  }
});
```

PS: if its possible with CSS only, tell me how please.

Note that the `ul` has mixed elements, like:

```
<li class="a">foo</li>
<li class="b">foo</li>
<li class="hr">foo</li>
<li class="c">foo</li>
<li class="a">foo</li>
<li class="hr">foo</li>
```

I need the 5th `li.hr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in pure CSS:

```
/* set rule: select every li.hr element after the 4th  */
ul > li.hr ~ li.hr ~ li.hr ~ li.hr ~ li.hr {
  color: green;
}
/* unset rule: select every li.hr element after the 5th  */
ul > li.hr ~ li.hr ~ li.hr ~ li.hr ~ li.hr ~ li.hr {
  /* reverse the rules set in the previous block here */
  color: black;
}
```

Caveat: The `~` selector is not supported by IE6. Works fine on everything else.

Comment: Neet! This is the best solution, because fast, and easy-to-use.

Comment: Everytime I think I know CSS I see answers like this.

Answer (score 17):

Despite the popular consensus, you can't use `:nth-child` here because it counts *all* children, regardless of whether or not they match the preceding selector.  Only *after* it grabs the nth element does it compare it to the selector to determine whether it matches.  So this: `ul li.hr:nth-child(5)` actually gets treated as `ul li:nth-child(5).hr`.  This might sound weird, but it strictly conforms to the CSS specification (see the [jQuery description](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)).

Luckily, jQuery provides the wonderful `:eq()` pseudo-class which allows you to filter by a zero-based index, *and* respects the preceding selector...

```
$("ul > li.hr:eq(4)").addClass("green");
```

I even tested this out to make sure it works...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .green { color:green; font-weight:bold; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("ul > li.hr:eq(4)").addClass("green"); 
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="a">foo</li>
    <li class="b">foo</li>
    <li class="hr">foo</li>
    <li class="c">foo</li>
    <li class="a">foo</li>
    <li class="hr">foo</li>
    <li class="a">foo</li>
    <li class="b">foo</li>
    <li class="hr">foo</li>
    <li class="c">foo</li>
    <li class="a">foo</li>
    <li class="hr">foo</li>
    <li class="a">foo</li>
    <li class="b">foo</li>
    <li class="hr">bar</li> <!-- 5th -->
    <li class="c">foo</li>
    <li class="a">foo</li>
    <li class="hr">foo</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agree with you. It is weird. `nth-child` is not working as expected.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for the example too, I'll use this later, and learn everything about eq. But the point is Borgar's with the pure CSS solution. (my favourite ^^) up for it

Comment: The problem with .eq() and :eq() is that it will only add the class once. He wants it to add the class every 5 times li.hr is present in the list.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [**nth-child**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) of jquery.

```
$("ul li.hr:nth-child(5)").addClass("green");
```

Comment: 'ul li.hr:eq(4)' will do the same thing, but in a shorter form.

Comment: This does not work, because the jQuery implementation of `nth-child` conforms to the [W3C CSS Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).  The selector in your answer only matches an `li` if it is the 5th child of a `ul` *and* has a class of `hr`.  I know it seems like nth-child is the answer at first glance, but in this particular scenario, it is not.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('ul').find('li.hr:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("green");
});
```

Reference: [:nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

**CSS3** offers a similar selector, have a read http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

would look like

```
li.hr:nth-child(5) {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: `nth-child` does not behave as expected.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`li.hr:nth-child(5)` will find an `.hr` that is *also* the fifth child in its `<ul>`. If I understand correctly, you're looking for the 5<sup>th</sup> `.hr`. Try:

```
$('ul').find('li.hr:eq(4)').addClass('green');
```

This isn't a single selector, but should work for your. For every `<ul>` it finds all `.hr` elements, and picks the fifth one.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xv6gX/

Answer (score 1):

```
var lis = $('ul li.hr');
if(lis.length >= 4) { 
    $(lis[4]).addClass('green'); 
}
```

Should do the trick. I've tested it in Firebug.

the :nth-child selector doesn't work as you'd expect it, since it doesn't take into account the class selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) there:

```
$("ul li.hr:nth-child(5)").addClass('green');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it this way.

```
if($("ul li.hr")[4]){
    $($("ul li.hr")[4]).addClass("green");
}
```